# Gravity Forms / Drop Down Fields - Empty dropdown after invalid submit

Tags: php, wordpress, populate, gravityforms, wordpress-hook

I have the code below to populate drop down fields dynamic:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_1', 'populate_dates' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_1', 'populate_dates' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_1', 'populate_dates' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_1', 'populate_dates' );

function populate_dates( $form ) {
  $post_id = ibs_id();
  foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
    if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-dates' ) === false ) {
        continue;
    }
    $the_date = array();
    $DatesArr = array();
    for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) 
    {
      $the_date[$i] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'date' . $i);
     if(!empty($the_date[$i])) 
     {        array_push($DatesArr, $the_date[$i][0]); }
    }
    $choices = array();
    foreach ( $DatesArr as $Date ) {
      $choices[] = array( 'text' => $Date, 'value' => $Date);
    }
    $field->choices = $choices;
  }
    return $form;
}
```

I m taking the id of the post with post method with the function ibs_id. The function is working great but when i click on submit with invalid inputs (for example i have no fill the requireds fields) the dropdown selections are disappearing.

I have to mention that other fields which are filled dynamically with ibs_id function to get post id are still filled in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `isSelected` to retain it selected. check below complete code.

```
 function populate_dates( $form ) {
          $post_id = ibs_id();
          foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
            if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-dates' ) === false ) {
                continue;
            }
            $the_date = array();
            $DatesArr = array();
            for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) 
            {
              $the_date[$i] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'date' . $i);
             if(!empty($the_date[$i])) 
             {        array_push($DatesArr, $the_date[$i][0]); }
            }
            $choices = array();
            foreach ( $DatesArr as $Date ) {
               $isselected=false;
               if($_POST['input_'.$field->id]==$Date)   $isselected=true;
              $choices[] = array( 'text' => $Date, 'value' => $Date,'isSelected' => $isselected );
            }
            $field->choices = $choices;
          }
            return $form;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately my problem is not that i don't keep it selected, but the choices are not coming after invalid submit. for example when i first open the form i have a dropdown with choices: Select a date (placeholder), 21 Aug 2018, 19 Sep 2018. But after click submit button and the submission is invalid i can see only the placeholder without dates!

Comment: Ok then check $post_id after invalid submit do you get same post_id or something else?

Comment: It s the same, that's why all other fields that uses post_id are populated after click on submit button. Only the dropdown lost it's values.

Comment: well I have tried with only $i value and its working fine, I want to know ibs_id(); what it will return share those values.

Comment: also share at admin side how  you store your custom meta values